# Find unknown parts

Tags: light-fixture

The specific part that I'm looking to replace is this light.  What kind of a light is it and how do I replace it?

But I have a more general question.  Is there a good place to look up unknown parts by their description, or do I always need to post pictures here?

[image: What type of light is this?]

Comment: What part do you want to replace, the whole fixture or just the enter piece?  It's usually cheaper to just replace the whole fixture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a LED lamp, where the bulbs are integrated into the fixture and are not replaceable. You will probably need to replace the whole fixture.

Just in case, look to see if there is a part number, possibly on the back of the fixture (against the ceiling).

EDIT: I googled the part number on the circuit board (Samsung e473485) and it is called a LED Downlight. You can find plenty on online hardware stores by searching for that phrase.

I personally don't like how non-serviceable those are (especially since, AFIAK, the electronics tend to fail before the LEDs will ever fail). Consider your replacement options.

Comment: More than likely, the back of the fixture base has a label saying something like "Do not disassemble; no user-serviceable parts inside".

Comment: That sounds like a challenge! ;)

Comment: @supertanker13  Yes, I've been wondering about the wisdom of non-replaceable parts in fixtures as well.   BTW I had to look up AFIAK!  and it's actually AFAIK!  LOL  Take care.

Comment: The “no user serviceable parts” statement is a legal notice as is do not disassemble. This keeps the MFG from being liable for damage after a repair  if the fixture then fails. Supertanker good job of tracking it down I was going to but luckily I read your answer first+
Keep the answers coming .  Holtorf you may find the driver has failed this is quite common with led fixtures the problem I have found is sourcing the drivers , in some cases they cost 1/2 the price of the fixture so it makes more sense to replace it.